# SVG path to create triangle with rounded corners

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create a simple svg path in the shape of a triangle with rounded corners.

I've started from this triangle:

```html
<svg width="440" height="440">
  <path d="M5,100 L70,5 L135,100 z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

But I'm struggling to add in the corners - this is as far as I've got:

```html
<svg width="440" height="440">
  <path d="M5,100 a10,10 1 0 1 -5,-10 L70,5 L135,90 a10,10 1 0 1 5,10  z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

What is the correct path coordinates to create the triangle with three smooth corners? Do I need to do some geometry to calculate the correct strart and end points or is there a tool I can use to configure the shape which will give me the coordinates the shape is made up of?

Comment: As a reusable solution, I wouldn't know anything but calculating the points. For a simple one-off, Inkscape can help.

Comment: @ccprog Inkscape looks useful ... not the simplest tool : 2 days later and I've not actually drawn a rounded corner triangle but working on it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inkscape has an option to convert the stroke of a path to a filled object. With that you can:

1. Draw a simple triangle and set fill to none.
2. Define a stroke with a width that is double the radius of the corner rounding you want to achieve.
3. Set `stroke-linejoin:round` (Fill and Stroke dialog -> Stroke style -> Round join).
4. Select from menu Path -> Stroke to Path.
5. Set to node selection mode. Now you can remove all nodes on the inner side.
   [image]
6. Set fill to none again and select a stroke to your liking.
   [image]